# Adding Title Tag to Featured Image in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Since WordPress 3.5, the title tag attribute is not included with featured images. I found the following piece of code which inserts a title tag attribute onto a featured image, however, it uses the page title as the image title.

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'my_img_title', 10, 2);
function my_img_title($attr, $attachment = null){
$attr['title'] = get_post($attachment->ID)->post_title;
return $attr;
}
```

However, I would like to use the image alt tag that is defined in the media manager as the image title tag. This is what I tried, but I'm not having any luck:

```
$attachment = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->id);
$mytitle = get_post_meta($thumb_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'my_img_title', 10, 2);
function my_img_title($attr, $attachment = null){
return str_replace('<img', '<img title="' . $mytitle . '" '  , $html);
return $attr;
```

Am I even close?

Comment: `$attr['title'] = get_post($attachment->ID)->post_title;` That should work -- are you sure you image isn't just named the same as the page? To debug, you can `print_r($attachment)` and see what that object actually is.

Comment: I tested this by changing the name of the page - the image title tag would also change.

Comment: Hmm, I've tested the code too and it works as expected. Sorry, I'm stumped!

Comment: Do I need to make any modifications to `<?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>`?

Comment: Nope, that code should be fine. Your filter is being called correctly, just the "attachment" object seems to be a page object instead of the media object. Perhaps a plugin is messing with things?